# How to remove duplicate names in an object with multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the object below with different arrays and I want to remove the duplicate names that are showing. How can I do that?

[How duplicate names look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/938as.png)

The data is being printed this way

[All data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiHo1.png)

The dsUserId is what is being repeated. And I want to be able to remove duplicate `dsUserId`

Here is where all the data is being generated.

```
  this.setState({
      user_connections: results.data.data.connections,
      newLeads: results2.data.data,
      promotion: results3.data.data,
      hasPromotion: results3.data.data.length === 0 ? false : true,
      promoPlan: promoPlan,
      toRemoveDays: excludedDays
    });

    console.log("All data", this.state.user_connections)
  }
```

And here is where the data is being rendered.

```
  <select
    id="user_select"
    style={{ width: "70%" }}
    name="selectedUser"
    onChange={e => {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim()
      });
    }}
    className="form-control"
  >
    <option value={null} disabled hidden selected>
      Please Select
    </option>
    {this.state.user_connections.map(u => (
      <option value={u.parentId} key={u.parentId}>
        {u.displayName}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
```

Comment: I think the better answer is to not return duplicate data from your data source. You'll avoid coding around it all over the frontend, letting the React code 'know less' about the data it receives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to achieve this for eg:

```
const userConnections = (connections) => {
    const uniqueIds = [];
    return connections.filter(connection => {
       if (!uniquesIds.includes(connection.dsUserId) {
           uniqueIds.push(connection.dsUserId);
           return connection;
       }
    })
};
```

and then :

```
user_connections: userConnections(results.data.data.connections)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the best way, but I would first make a Set of all the unique dsUserIds and then filter the first in the user_connections array for each dsUserId:

```
let tsUserIds = [];
this.state.user_connections.forEach(user => {
  tsUserIds.push(user.dsUserId);
})
tsUserIds = [...new Set(tsUserIds)]; // filters out the duplicates
let uniqueConnections = [];
tsUserIds.forEach(id => {
  uniqueConnections.push(this.state.user_connections.filter(user => user.dsUserId === id)[0]);
})
console.log(uniqueConnections);
```